# AngularJS override scope of transclude scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Initialize of the dir call:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <dir arr="[{name: 'Dennis'}, {name: 'Bob'}]">
    <h3>Working as not wanted: {{$parent.obj.name}}</h3>
    <h3>Not working as wanted: {{obj.name}}</h3>
  </dir>
</div>
```

And the directive is self:

```
angular.module("myApp",[]).directive('dir', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            arr: '='
        }, 
        template: '<span ng-repeat="obj in arr"><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></span>',
        link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller, transcludeFn) {
            //transcludeFn(scope);
        }
    }
});
```

From docs `transcludeFn` with first argument should replace the scope of the transclude isolated scope, but it doesn't. [Here is the codepen working sample to test/work with.](https://codepen.io/Crackeraki/pen/GxdYKr?editors=1010)

Comment: didnt understand what exactly you needed? what you need exactly?

Comment: I need the scope of the ng-transclude to be same with parent scope.

Comment: [once check this plunk](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oqaQxg?editors=1010)

Comment: you do an awesome thing, you have custom scope in the transclude, which is what i want to have. But what in fact is needed, that the scope which is created by directive, was used by transclude, so we can have the obj within transclude

Comment: if you see `<h3>Not working as wanted: {{arr | json}}</h3>`, it is using the directive scope itself

Comment: Even though that line is coming from `ng-transclude`, it can access the directive's scope.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Crackeraki/pen/KoGEJb?editors=1010
here is added controller over html.

Comment: If you check this pen https://codepen.io/Crackeraki/pen/KoGEJb?editors=1010
, what i noticed is that the transcludeFn is not touching ng-transclude at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After huge research, I figure out that, until now there is no way to modify the scope of translucde. So I moved out the repeat, which broke a bit the logic of this quesiton and as temporary solution I made this one.
html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="app">
  <dir obj="obj" ng-repeat="obj in arr">
    <h3>Looking to get: {{obj.name}}</h3>
  </dir>
</div>
```

and javascript:

```
ular.module("myApp", []).controller('app', function($scope){
  $scope.arr = [{name: 'Dennis'}, {name: 'Bob'}];
}).directive('wsort', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            obj: '='
        }, template: '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>'
    }
});
```

Where we specify repeat outside of the directive and use the obj within as we need.

Answer (score 1):

ng-transclude will leave the content as it is whatever inside the directive element and those elements inside directive still look for a parent scope only.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <dir arr="[{name: 'Dennis'}, {name: 'Bob'}]">
        <h3>Working as not wanted: {{$parent.obj.name}}</h3>
    </dir>
</div>

angular.module("myApp",[]).directive('dir', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            arr: '='
        }, template: '<span ng-repeat="obj in arr"><ng-transclude></ng-transclude> <h3>Not working as wanted: {{obj.name}}</h3></span>',
        link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller, transcludeFn) {
            //transcludeFn(scope);
        }
    }
});
```

You can view the demo [here](https://codepen.io/srigar/pen/jzvRQq?editors=1010)

Comment: The point is to keep `<h3>Not working as wanted: {{obj.name}}</h3>` in the html. The reason I added `//transcludeFn(scope);` is somehow to provide what scope should transclude use.

Comment: `<h3>Working as not wanted: {{$parent.obj.name}}</h3>` this line should not give the name

`<h3>Not working as wanted: {{obj.name}}</h3> in the html. The reason I added //transcludeFn(scope);` this line should give the name

Answer (score 0):

`ng-transclude` will take the `scope` of the `directive` in which it is present

**Please check this directive code:**

```
angular.module("myApp",[]).directive('dir', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            arr: '='
        }, template: '<span ng-repeat="obj in arr"><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></span>',
    link: function(scope, el, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
      scope.arr = [{name: 'Dennis'}, {name: 'Bob'}];
      transclude(scope, function(clone, scope) {
        // this takes the parent scope
      });
    }
    }
});
```

**Html:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <dir arr="arr">
    <h3>Working as not wanted: {{$parent.obj.name}}</h3>
    <h3>Not working as wanted: {{arr | json}}</h3>
  </dir>
</div>
```

[**Here is a slackblitz for the same**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oqaQxg?editors=1010)

Comment: I added an answer for you so that, you can check here directly instead of going to that link everywhere.

Comment: now check https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rdqPrv?editors=1010 if I change the `scope` from `transclude fn` it changed the directive `scope` too

Comment: `scope.arr = [{name: 'Dennis'}, {name: 'Bob'}];` this is new array, not the one we are sending from html.

Comment: even that new array I m assignig in directive scope. but not transclude scope\

Comment: looks nice, but yet `{{obj.name}}` is still not working

Comment: check this [check this latest one](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rdqPrv?editors=1010)

Comment: This is far from the result, but I guess we can't make it with repeat in the of the directive, so I will reward you with the bounty and will write my own answer to this post.

Comment: Mean while I ll research more and transclusion and keep updating you.